# Hierarchical Tables

Tags: tables, fonts, graphics, bibtex, pdftex

Why this code is not working, my tables are not fully shown after running,

```
\usepackage{booktabs}
\newcommand{\ra}[1]{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{#1}}
\begin{table*}\centering
\ra{1.3}
\begin{tabular}{@{}rrrrcrrrcrrr@{}}\toprule
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{$w = 8$} & \phantom{abc}& \multicolumn{3}{c}{$w = 16$} &
\phantom{abc} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{$w = 32$}\\
\cmidrule{2-4} \cmidrule{6-8} \cmidrule{10-12}
& $t=0$ & $t=1$ & $t=2$ && $t=0$ & $t=1$ & $t=2$ && $t=0$ & $t=1$ & $t=2$\\ \midrule
$dir=1$\\
$c$ & 0.0790 & 0.1692 & 0.2945 && 0.3670 & 0.7187 & 3.1815 && -1.0032 & -1.7104 & -21.7969\\
$c$ & -0.8651& 50.0476& 5.9384&& -9.0714& 297.0923& 46.2143&& 4.3590& 34.5809& 76.9167\\
$c$ & 124.2756& -50.9612& -14.2721&& 128.2265& -630.5455& -381.0930&& -121.0518& -137.1210& -220.2500\\
$dir=0$\\
$c$ & 0.0357& 1.2473& 0.2119&& 0.3593& -0.2755& 2.1764&& -1.2998& -3.8202& -1.2784\\
$c$ & -17.9048& -37.1111& 8.8591&& -30.7381& -9.5952& -3.0000&& -11.1631& -5.7108& -15.6728\\
$c$ & 105.5518& 232.1160& -94.7351&& 100.2497& 141.2778& -259.7326&& 52.5745& 10.1098& -140.2130\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{Caption}
\end{table*}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please make your code snippet compilable.

Comment: It misses many things like `\begin` and `\end{document}` and possibly have more errors that we will check after you fix it (See here what I mean https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that). Also to make code seen as supposed, select it and press {} button

Comment: I already added \begin and \end{document}

Comment: @JSS11 we both mean that you have to edit your post and make the code compilable (There is not \begin and \end{document} here). Also when you want to someone to see your comment you have to "call his name with a @ before it like: @koleygr"

Comment: The table code works fine, but the table is likely too wide, making it go out of the page on the right side. For general tips about such a problem, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/332902 You have a lot to go on, for example you can remove the `\phantom{abc}`s, and you can perhaps use e.g. `\multicolumn{2}{l}{$dir=1$}` instead of just `$dir=1$`. And you can reduce space between columns with `\addtolength\tabcolsep{-2pt}`. If you want more specific advice, please edit your example to include `\documentclass` and any margin settings, so that we can see how narrow the table has to be.

Answer (score 2):

You can make your table fit on a standard text width:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx}

\newcommand{\mc}[3]{\multicolumn{#1}{#2}{#3}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table*}
\centering
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{
  @{\extracolsep{\fill}}
  c
  S[table-format=-2.4]
  S[table-format=-2.4]
  S[table-format=-2.4]
  S[table-format=-2.4]
  S[table-format=-3.4]
  S[table-format=-3.4]
  S[table-format=-3.4]
  S[table-format=-3.4]
  S[table-format=-3.4]
}
\toprule
& \mc{3}{c}{$w = 8$} & \mc{3}{c}{$w = 16$} & \mc{3}{c}{$w = 32$}\\
\cmidrule{2-4} \cmidrule{5-7} \cmidrule{8-10}
& {$t=0$} & {$t=1$} & {$t=2$}
& {$t=0$} & {$t=1$} & {$t=2$}
& {$t=0$} & {$t=1$} & {$t=2$} \\
\midrule
\mc{10}{@{}l}{$\mathit{dir}=1$} \\
$c$ &   0.0790 &   0.1692 &   0.2945 &   0.3670 &    0.7187 &    3.1815 &   -1.0032 &   -1.7104 &  -21.7969\\
$c$ &  -0.8651 &  50.0476 &   5.9384 &  -9.0714 &  297.0923 &   46.2143 &    4.3590 &   34.5809 &   76.9167\\
$c$ & 124.2756 & -50.9612 & -14.2721 & 128.2265 & -630.5455 & -381.0930 & -121.0518 & -137.1210 & -220.2500\\
\midrule
\mc{10}{@{}l}{$\mathit{dir}=0$}\\
$c$ &   0.0357 &   1.2473 &   0.2119 &   0.3593 &   -0.2755 &    2.1764 &   -1.2998 &   -3.8202 &   -1.2784\\
$c$ & -17.9048 & -37.1111 &   8.8591 & -30.7381 &   -9.5952 &   -3.0000 &  -11.1631 &   -5.7108 &  -15.6728\\
$c$ & 105.5518 & 232.1160 & -94.7351 & 100.2497 &  141.2778 & -259.7326 &   52.5745 &   10.1098 & -140.2130\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\caption{Caption}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

In the first four numeric columns, the format is `-2.4` because the minus sign is wider than the additional digit.

If the table doesn't fit, add `\small` in front of it or, in tough cases, `\footnotesize`.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your table has two main problems:

1. you don't need to add a fictitious column to separate the `\cmidrule`s, there are the options `(lr)` for that (`l` = line shorter on the left and `r` = line shorter on the right)
2. your table is too wide to fit a page, I suggest to use `sideways` and print it landscape. (Since you didn't post a complete MWE, I don't know which documentclass you are using, I used `book`.)

Moreover, I added the `dcolumn` package for a better alignment of your numbers to the decimal point (this is optional, of course).

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\newcommand{\ra}[1]{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{#1}}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{dcolumn} 
\newcolumntype{d}{D{.}{.}{4}} 

\begin{document}
\begin{sidewaystable}
\centering
\ra{1.3}
\begin{tabular}{@{}r*9{d}@{}}\toprule
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{$w = 8$} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{$w = 16$}  & \multicolumn{3}{c}{$w = 32$}\\
\cmidrule(lr){2-4} \cmidrule(lr){5-7} \cmidrule(l){8-10}
& \multicolumn{1}{r}{$t=0$} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{$t=1$} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{$t=2$} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{$t=0$} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{$t=1$} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{$t=2$} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{$t=0$} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{$t=1$} & \multicolumn{1}{r@{}}{$t=2$}\\ \midrule
$dir=1$\\
$c$ & 0.0790 & 0.1692 & 0.2945 & 0.3670 & 0.7187 & 3.1815 & -1.0032 & -1.7104 & -21.7969\\
$c$ & -0.8651& 50.0476& 5.9384& -9.0714& 297.0923& 46.2143& 4.3590& 34.5809& 76.9167\\
$c$ & 124.2756& -50.9612& -14.2721& 128.2265& -630.5455& -381.0930& -121.0518& -137.1210& -220.2500\\
$dir=0$\\
$c$ & 0.0357& 1.2473& 0.2119& 0.3593& -0.2755& 2.1764& -1.2998& -3.8202& -1.2784\\
$c$ & -17.9048& -37.1111& 8.8591& -30.7381& -9.5952& -3.0000& -11.1631& -5.7108& -15.6728\\
$c$ & 105.5518& 232.1160& -94.7351& 100.2497& 141.2778& -259.7326& 52.5745& 10.1098& -140.2130\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{Caption}
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

[image]